# Count distinct values (text/numbers) in concatenation of two columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Example: I have a list of scientific studies with two columns, one with author, another with date, and would like to know how many distinct studies I have and also how many unique studies by first letter in the author's name. 
In this example:

```
 1    Consales      2012
 2    Coogan        1996
 3    Cook          1992
 4    Cook          2000
 5    Cook          2002
 6    Cook          2006
 7    Cossarizza    1993
 8    Cossarizza    1993
 9    David         2016
10    Daniel        2014
```

the result is a total 9 distinct studies (Cossarizza 1993 is duplicated), 7 studies starting with the letter C and 2 studies with the letter D. There are empty cells in the data base.

I would like to apply a possible solution to a list with  approximately 700 studies (some duplicates) I created in Excel.

Comment: You lost me on why you want to use just the first letter of the author's name.  As you point out, there are many authors whose names start with the same first letter.  Maybe the odds are good that the letter in combination with the date could be unique.  However, 1. it seems like you're needlessly tempted fate and risking getting the wrong results.  2. It's more work and complication to extract the first letter than to use the whole name.  Can you clarify why you want to do it that way?

Comment: I would like to count the studies by first letter of author because I have an index by all the 26 letters of the alphabet that takes me to the authors and I show how many studies are there for authors starting with letter A, B, C etc

Answer (score 1):

For my Excel Version (Excel For Mac, Version 16.25), there's a button named "Remove Duplicates" in **Data** tab.
[Screenshot for the button at here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYk5u.png)

You could select multiple columns that you wanted to concatenate. If all selected columns are equal, the row will be removed.

Comment: my comments are now allowed